# Custom tag in JSP not working with Spring Session filter

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jsp-tags, spring-session

I am trying to implement Spring Session on a legacy application. Everything seems to be working except I found an issue where a custom TagSupport has a problem.

I am not very familiar with tags, but I will try to explain the problem. The TagSupport class gets an object out of the session and does a check on it to see if some portion of the JSP should be displayed or not.

The code looks similar to this:

```
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    //get object from session
    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession(true);
    Foo foo = (Foo)session.getAttribute("foo");

    if(foo!= null){
        return Tag.EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
    }
    return Tag.SKIP_BODY;
}
```

The problem is.. When I debug I see the code inside the doStartTag() method is executed multiple times. The first two times `foo` is populated correctly and the method gives the desired return value, but then it executes the method 3 more times and `foo` is null. (the tag is called twice on the page I am trying to load.)

If I remove the `springSessionRepositoryFilter` from my web.xml the doStartTag method is still executed multiple times, but every time the `foo`object is populated and the web page renders correctly.

I'm not sure why the `doStartTag()` code is executed multiple times although I don't think that's the problem. I verified the controller is only hit once. I've tried debugging what happens in between but it's very in the weeds. I can also see I have two session objects, one called `JESSIONID` and the `SESSION`. I'm not sure if that's a problem either.

I'm in a little over my head and if anyone has any pointers it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

I implemented spring session using the guide here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-xml.html
In the process I updated some spring libraries so a library conflict isn't out of the question.

Comment: Are there multiple occurrences of the tag on the concerned page?